# Find the angle between a point and vehicle

Tags: algorithm, math, angle

[image: Path of Vehicle]

With the picture above, I am trying to snap a picture of the object (point) behind the black wall or in front of the black wall. The blue wall is a glass partition and allows the camera to see through the wall and snap a picture. If the angle of the camera on the vehicle bounces off the black wall, no picture can be taken as the object cannot be seen. If it's seen through the blue partition, the camera can take a picture.

The Cartesian points for the objects are given and the distance of the wall from the vehicle's path is given as well.

I was using Pythagorean's Theorem and some trigonometry with right angles, but they are not always right angles at times.

How would I go about solving this issue or starting it in the first place?

EDIT:

For the output, a cartesian coordinates would be:

- Distance of the wall from the vehicles path: 2
- For the blue partition wall: Begin (3,2), End (5,2)
- Objects located at: (2,3), (6,3)

The output should be 2 because the problem attempts to take a picture of each object, but with the least amount of pictures possible to encompass all objects.

Comment: What's not always right angles? Do you mean the car's trajectory is not always parallel to the wall/glass?

Comment: @SirGuy With the picture above, the current vehicles position and the positions of the objects, does not create a right angle. This is why it's not always going to be right angles between one point, all points, and the vehicle's position.

Comment: @bhazero025 can you paste an example input of cartesian points and what should be the output for it, it will help me a lot to understand the issue more correctly. Thanks

Comment: @zenwraight Please see updated post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just need a method for calculating angles between vectors. Using the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) `dot(a,b)` and this identity:

```
|a||b|cos(t) = dot(a, b)
```

where `a` and `b` are your vectors and `t` is the angle between them, you can find the angle between any two vectors.

To actually find out if the car can see the object through the glass, you can do this by:

```
1. Find the angle between the car's velocity and the near edge of the wall/glass interface.
2. Find the angle between the car's velocity and the far edge of the wall/glass interface.
3. Find the angle between the car's velocity and the look vector from the car to the object.
4. Check if Angle(1) < Angle(3) < Angle(2).
```

This is not the most computationally efficient method of computing this, but I don't want to take all the fun away, and I think this is a fairly understandable method.

Comment: Thank you for the response. After doing the analysis, I'm running into some issues. Angle 1 is bigger than Angle 2 at all times. Here's my code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/37241da4e85230d01ce3b2f1f73cece7

Comment: @bhazero025 I'm guessing those coordinates are relative to whatever origin you have set, the vectors these questions refer to are the differences in positions. The look vector from the car to the object is then `object_position - car_position`.